# txt file into excel format

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

Can someone help me with my code? I'm trying to get a specific line that contains some specific text into an Excel.

It would also be great if the text doesn't overwrite the text in my excel:)

```
import xlwt
import xlrd


book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet('First Sheet')  # Add a sheet

#f = open(r'C:/Users/mib/Desktop/TEST1/test.txt', 'r+')
def check():
   # with open('example.txt') as f:
   f = open(r'C:/Users/M/Desktop/TEST1/test.txt')
        datafile = f.readlines()
    found = False  
    for line in datafile:
        if sh run in line:
            # found = True 
            return True
#data = f.readlines() # read all lines at once

    
for i in range(len(data)):
  row = data[i].split('\n')
  

  for j in range(len(row)):
    # if operator.contains(i, "System serial number"):
    #if 'System serial number' in f.read():
    ws.write(i, j, row[j])  # Write to cell i, j

book.save(r'C:/Users/M/Desktop/TEST1/test' + '.xls')
f.close()

 return False
```

Answer (score 0):

for write content in a new line use openpyxl library

Comment: Can you mabye provide an example?